# how to debug/solve recursive ajax appending duplicates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I am currently developing a pure JS/Jquery application and have encountered a problem.

**Scenario**
We have a class that takes an array of ID's. And build's itself with an Ajax call to a Parse.com Database. Once build, it appends some data (Id, Name, ...) to a `<div>` list, pop a new ID of the list and call's itself until there are no more ID's in the array. The result is a DIV with a list of all the build objects.

**Here is the Class in Pseudo Code**

```
function classSomething(ListOfIds,...){
var aListId= ListOfIds.pop();
$.ajax({
    url: '<secret URL to Parse Database>' + aListId,
    dataType: 'json',
    async : true,
    success: function(response) {

        this.id = response.id;
        this.name = response.name;
        this.address = response.Address;

        ...

        var innerHTML = '<li><div class="aclassObject">'+ this.id + ... + '</div></li>';

        $('#TheList').append(innerHTML)

        if(ListOfIds.length >0){
                new classSomething(ListOfIds,...)
        }

    }
}
```

**Problem**
The problem is that the list sometimes has duplicate elements. Unfortunately when I debug the JS, It works perfectly 100% of the time, but when executed normally it will have "random" duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, to remove all duplicates so that each recursive call will have a uniq array of ids. You can just grab that filter expression I put and see if that solves the problem, but my guess is that the async nature of all the calls is what is creating the issue.

But, what if an ajax call takes a bit longer to return than another? Since it is all async, you could send of one without an ID, but get a return of a previous one, that will hand it back (with no knowledge that you just removed it). Here is some pseudo code, perhaps to spark ideas.

```
function request(id) {    

    // return the AJAX promise
    return $.ajax({
        url: '<secret URL to Parse Database>' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        async : true
    });
}

function sendTheRequest(ids,....) {
    // you probably don't need this filter if you go the promise route
    const id = ids.filter(function(item, pos) {
                 return ids.indexOf(item) == pos;
               })
         return request(id).then(function(response){
            // deal with your returned data
            // conditional. if still 'ids', do recursive, call again
              if(ids.length) sendTheRequest(ids,...)
         });
}

function putAllIds(ids){
    return sendTheRequest(ids);
}

putAllIds().done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}
```